# Unable to fetch user using Facebook js sdk v2.10 on Firefox

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, polymer-2.x

I am trying to add facebook authentication on our website using Facebook Javascript SDK **v2.10**. My aim is to login via Facebook and then fetch the user which was authenticated.
The problem I am facing is that on **Firefox**, I am unable to fetch the authenticated user.

I have created a test page [**HERE**](https://app-dev.dekkho.com/)

When you click on the button 'Login via Facebook', the `FB.login` function is called. When the response is received, I am calling the `FB.api` function. Following is my code

```
FB.login(function(response) {
              let p1 = document.createElement('p');
              p1.innerHTML = "FB.login response follows:<br>"+ JSON.stringify(response);
              document.body.appendChild(p1)
              FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,first_name'},
                  function(response) {
                      let p2 = document.createElement('p');
                      p2.innerHTML = "FB.api response follows:<br>"+ JSON.stringify(response);
                      document.body.appendChild(p2)
                  });
          });
```

In Chrome,the callback of `FB.api` is called and the response is received,but, in Firefox, this is not happening. Kindly help me figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I was using Facebook sdk in Polymer app. The sdk documentation suggests adding the sdk initialization code in `index.html`.

But, for Polymer, you need to add the code in the `connectedCallback` method of your root app (`my-app.html` if you are using `polymer-starter-kit`)

For reasons unknown, the `webcomponent-loader.js` blocks Facebook initialization on Firefox, if sdk code is added in index.html.